# Pidyon Haben Question

Tags: riddle, pidyon-haben

How is it possible to make a פדיון הבן by giving money to someone who is not a כהן?

Answer (score 4):

the Chasam Sofer says if there is no כהן available and a person, who has never had a Pidyon Haben, has reached old age or if a person just doesn’t want to wait because who knows he will die shortly,then he should give the פדיון to a כהנת who Married a Yisroel without a  ברכה and have in mind a תנאי that he really doesn’t want to be יוצא the מצוה with this, should he find a כהן in the future. Then, he should be פודה himself a second time, this time with a ברכה.  Rav Yaakov Emden in his  "ו( כ אות בכור פדיון הלכות) סדור says the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is no halakhic basis to do Pidyon Haben by anyone but a Kohen, as the kohanim have taken the place of the first born.

A more legitimate question would be whether a Kohen today(who is ultimately a sofek Kohen) can actually receive money for Pidyon HaBen?