# Baby born bein hashmoshos -- when to make pidyon haben?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, pidyon-haben

We know that if a baby is born bein hashmoshos we make the bris according to if the baby was born on the following day (i.e. if it was bein hashmoshos between Monday and Tuesday we would count 8 days from Tuesday.)

What does one do in such a case in regards to making a Pidyon HaBen? Do we also count from Tuesday? I don't have any particular reason to think this should be any different than the bris, though I don't know so I'm asking.

Comment: If we really consider the baby to be born ke'ilu the 'next day' at bein hashmashot, why should that halachic reality change from mitzvah to mitzvah? Metzius is metzius.

Comment: @EiluV'Eilu, re "If we really consider the baby to be born ke'ilu the 'next day' at bein hashmashot, why should that halachic reality change from mitzvah to mitzvah? Metzius is metzius.": I doubt we so consider. I think we are _m'supakim_ as to what day he was born and choose one of the sides of the _safek_ when necessary, e.g. when deciding when to do _mila_; this question wonders which choice would be made when deciding when to do _pidyon haben_.

Comment: Also, how do "we know that if a baby is born bein hasmoshos we make the bris according to if the baby was born on the following day"?

Comment: @SethJ In fact, that statement is not true. If the baby is born Friday evening Bein Hashemashot, the bris is the following Sunday, unlike if he was born on Shabbat when the bris is on Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA, well, I'm be willing to give an OP wiggle room for a generalization for the sake of brevity and simplicity. I'm less satisfied with authoritative statements without sources. <Goes to look up sources for previously posted answer.>

Comment: **Comments removed:** Comments are for improving the question (e.g. by seeking clarification or offering pointers to relevant material), not for extended discussions.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29066/why-are-pidyon-haben-ceremonies-done-towards-evening

Answer (score 2):

See Yoreh Deah 305:11. The Shach says to make a pidyon haben only after a lunar month has passed (average lunar month is 29.5 days + 44 minutes).  The Magen Avraham in contrast says to make a pidyon haben on the 31st day.  The Aruch Hashulchan explains that the Magen Avraham's opinion is a leniency, allowing the pidyon haben to be done even at a time before the full lunar month of 29.5 days + 44 minutes has passed, not a stringency requiring we wait even beyond the passing of a full lunar month.  Thus, the time to do the pidyon haben would be on the suffik 30/31st day, but it must be late enough in the day so that at least 29.5 days and 44 minutes have passed since the time of the birth.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Chona and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

When we have a doubt regarding a biblical command, we take a stringent approach. This is known as ספק דאורייתא לחומרה.

When we are obligated to do something at a set time, and especially when that time is dependent on another phenomenon or event, it is imperative that we know when the appropriate time is. This is why two days of Yom Tov were established outside of the range to which the court in Jerusalem could send messengers notifying the public of the new moon each month.

In terms of these particular commandments, Millah and Pidyon HaBen, there is an added dimension, which is the tension between the urgency of the Mitzvah, which would incline one towards early action, and the potential problem of acting *too* early and thus not fulfilling it at all, since the set time hasn't arrived yet.  Thus there is a question of *how* to be stringent - do you lean "early" so you don't miss a day to perform the Mitzvah (Millah carries [Kareth](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2010/04/what-is-kares.html) if left unfulfilled; Pidyon HaBen does not, but it is mandated at a set time, and by pushing it off a day you miss that time), or do you lean "late" out of a fear that doing it too early is not valid at all? Which option is considered לחומרה?

In short, we do not allow premature Berith Millah, as it may be invalid. (I believe there is some debate about this, but this is how we hold.)  The same concern exists for Pidyon HaBen.  What is *not* a shared concern between Millah and Pidyon HaBen is the severity of delaying the Mitzvah.

[Apparently](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5179/5), in some limited circumstances, unlike Millah, Pidyon *could*, in theory, be done on one day without a Berachah (possibly 'Al Tenai), and then again on a different day (possibly with a Berachah if the first had been 'Al Tenai).  Physically, it would be impossible for Berith Millah to be done twice, obviously.  However, this is mentioned as a possible solution where there is no proper Kohen available, not where timing is an issue.

Furthermore, there is a debate among Posekim as to how we calculate the timing, and the practice of performing the Mitzvah on the 31st day is a way to ensure that it is not done prematurely according to any opinion.  In essence, we are already in a situation of ספק דאורייתא, due to this dispute, and we hold that חומרה, in this case, means delaying it by a day to be sure.

I have not seen a direct answer in a Teshuvah about this, but all the Halachic calculus leads me to the conclusion that we would delay the Pidyon HaBen until the Safek Day 31/32.

Comment: Though one can give the money to a kohein early and say the pidyon won't come into effect until the proper time.

Comment: What is the set time for pidyon haben?

Comment: @DoubleAA one month.

Comment: @DoubleAA, interesting. Post an answer.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing. There is a special mitzva for Milah to be on day eight. Pidyon haben can be anytime after one month. Who cares if it's three days later or 5 years later?

Comment: I don't know if such an option is preferable to just waiting.

Comment: @DoubleAA (I'm not sure why I didn't get a ping.) You've never heard of what? That it's set at one month? It's in the Pasuk, no?

Comment: The pasuk says one month and older. I don't know what's special about the first day of that period. Unlike Milah where the eighth day is specifically special.

Comment: @DoubleAA, what about Zerizim?

Comment: Sure, but I would think that's an external consideration.

Comment: @double aa yeah, that's why I avoided it until now.